# Is it right to use Django-rest-framework alongside django views

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm a Django developer, and a while ago I started using DRF for the first time in a project that had AngularJS. The project after that I was forced to go back to the old way of doing development but I wanted to continue using DRF so I decided to use in all the AJAX calls in the system instead of using AjaxMixins alongside Django CBVs.

The problem is, I have a senior at work who told me that this isn't a clean way to use DRF or django CBV and we have to either use django CBVs or DRF and not both of them together.

So, the thing is, I'm not convinced. I still think it's not wrong or an unclean way.

I thought I'd ask the community about it. Is it wrong, right, clean, unclean.. and how do you handle AJAX in your projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DRF` as `django CBV's` because DRF can return/render `HTML`, so, you will get same result. It would be a bit harder. But, also, you need to ask yourselves , if you will need a mobile app for your platform, an API will be needed, so if you don't use DRF now,  you will need to use it later and it will be tedious.